# Sitecore: Template field source dynamic targetting based on current SiteContext

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

Basically we currently have a multisite setup on a single sitecore installation. Thus we have a structure like this under the content node:

- Site 1

  - Content 1
- Site 2

  - Content 2

Now of course we wish to reuse our templates as much as we can so we would have a template like this:

```
Templatename: Webpage
Sections: Data
Fields: Title, Body, Image
```

Now for the "Image" field source we would set it to something like `/Media Library/Images` normally but since we have 2 seperate sites we wanted to mirror the structure in the media library as well like:

- Media Library

  - Site 1

    - Images
  - Site 2

    - Images

But how would we go about defining the source then on the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no easy way to accomplish what you want.
You have to overwrite "Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image" with your own copy off that class.

Then rewrite most of the BrowseImage method, and find some way to select what path it should pick.

You also have to do that to the command "webedit:chooseimage", if you support webedit.

Comment: I took a look at the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image` class. Basically my target in this case is this line: `options2.Root = item3;` where it got filled off this.Source by the lines `string text = StringUtil.GetString(new string[] { this.Source, "/sitecore/media library" });` and `Item item3 = Client.ContentDatabase.GetItem(text, language);` and I noticed that the webedit command runs off basicly copy-paste code also accessing the Source property. Thus I conclude from this that I best make an Image class that inherits from the original and override the Source property.